# How to show the norm of the residual in GMRES minimization problem?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, vectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I couldn't quite catch the relationship between QR and it. What I'm confused about is what S and C mean, and how can I make desired proof?

Let $e_i^{n} $be the i-th unit vector in $C^n$ The solution of the minimization task

$\min\limits_{y \in C^k} \|H_k y - \|r_0 \|_2 e_1^{(k+1)}\|_2$

in the k-th step of the GMRES procedure is denoted by $y_k$. Furthermore let

$v_{k} := H_k y - \| r_0 \|_2 e_1^{(k+1)}$

The sine and cosine values of the Givens rotations are denoted for j = 1, . . . , k by $s_j$ and $c_j$ , respectively

In that case, how can I prove the norm of the residual in the k-th step holds?

$\| r_k \|_2 = \| r_0 \|_2 | s_1, s_2, .... , s_k |$